# How can I have a Discord bot await my message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a simple discord bot, this is my first time doing so. I want the Discord bot to await my message before continuing but I can't seem to get this to work.
How can I have the Discord bot wait before continuing on? Also, I know my "throw new Error"'s might not be super correct; I wasn't sure of another way to stop the run.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class NewgameCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('newgame', 'managment', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === "staff")) {
      return message.channel.send("Only staff members can set up games!");
    }
    const gameEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('New MvM Mondays Game!')
      .setDescription('Add description here.')
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setTimestamp();
    const twoCitiesMissionsDisplayed = "\`\`\`\n1 - Empire Escalation\n2 - Metro Malice\n3 - Hamlet Hostility\n4 - Bavarian Botbash\`\`\`";
    const twoCitiesMissionsArray = ['Empire Escalation', 'Metro Malice', 'Hamlet Hostility', 'Bavarian Botbash'];
    const numOfMissions = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    message.channel.send("What Two Cities mission?");
    message.channel.send(twoCitiesMissionsDisplayed);
    message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
      {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
        const chosenMission = collected.first().content;
        if (!numOfMissions.includes(chosenMission)) {
          message.channel.send("You chose an invalid number!");
          throw new Error("Chose invalid mission number");
        }   
      }).catch(() => {
        message.channel.send('No answer after 30 seconds, operation canceled.');
        throw new Error("Took too long to respond.");
      });
    message.channel.send("Default classes? (yes/no)");
    message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
      {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
        const classesAnswer = collected.first().content;
        if (!numOfMissions.includes(collected.first().content)) {
          message.channel.send("All you had to do was say \"yes\" or \"no\"...");
          throw new Error("Didn't say \"yes\" or \"no\"");
        }       
      }).catch(() => {
        message.channel.send('No answer after 30 seconds, operation canceled.');
        throw new Error("Took too long to respond.");
      });
  }
}
```

What I see in Discord:
[image: What I see in Discord]

Answer (score 2):

We can detect timeouts using the catch block of the awaitMessages promise. Then, we can make it emit an error after timeout. Here is an example.

```
function filter(m){
    if(m.author.id != message.author.id) return false;
    if (!numOfMissions.includes(chosenMission)) {
        m.channel.send('You chose an invalid number!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}  
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const chosenMission = collected.first().content;
        message.channel.send(`You chose the ${chosenMission} mission`);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        message.channel.send('No answer after 30 seconds, operation canceled.');
    });
```

As you can see, I included the valid-number-check in the filter. This can allow the message collector not to end even if an invalid number is entered.

Also, I included `errors: ['time']` in the options of the `awaitMessages()` function. This tells the function to throw an error when the time is up (30 seconds in this case), and the error will cause the code to fall in the `catch` block of the promise.